# Encoding and decoding of the character references

Tags: html

if I use character reference in html file how that character reference is saved on the server hard disk and when the web server sends the file on browser request, how the browser will decode the character reference?

My Nginx web server is configured to not send character encoding in the header I have set character encoding in the meta tag on page level to utf8.

Comment: The character references are stored and served exactly as you save them. I don't know what magic you expect to be happening here.

Comment: What's a character reference? An HTML entity such as `&amp;` or `&#0123;`? It will be sent as is (it's only plain ASCII after all)

Answer (score 2):

A character reference like `&#123;` is just text characters as far as storing on disk or sending over the network are considered. The same applies to entity references like `&eacute;`, which are called “named character references” in HTML5 drafts.

When a browser parses an HTML document that it got from a server (or from local disk, or otherwise), it will process character and entity references using its built-in routines that implement the definitions for such concepts. This a purely local operation in the browser. Parsing a (numeric) character reference is a straighforward operation, where the browser interprets the notation as denoting the character with the given Unicode number. Parsing an entity reference involves in practice simple table lookup, using a table of some kind that maps names to numbers.

The character encoding does not affect this. A key part in the very idea of using character and entity references is that they let you specify a character independently of the character encoding of the document (including characters that cannot be represented as such in that encoding).